# How to create a fault tolerant JobStep

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch project where I have several jobs. I moduralized them in a single job to execute them sequentially like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("job1")
private Job job1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("job2")
private Job job2;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("job3")
private Job job3;

@Bean(name = "step1")
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").job(job1).build();
}

@Bean(name = "step2")
public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2").job(job2).build();
}

@Bean(name = "step3")
public Step step3() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3").job(job3).build();
}

@Bean(name = "parentJob")
public Job parentJob(@Qualifier("step1") Step step1, @Qualifier("step2") Step step2, @Qualifier("step3") Step step3) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("parentJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .repository(jobRepository)
            .start(step1)
            .next(step2)
            .next(step3)
            .build();
}
```

However if one of the `JobSteps` fail the parent job fails as well. Is there any mechanism to render fault tolerant all the `JobSteps` so that if one of them fails the parent job continues?

Comment: Could you possibly build each step first (in a try/catch within a for loop), based on whether it returns correctly add the object to a list and pass the list through to parent job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking for a conditional flow as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#conditionalFlow) i.e. you want to move on to next job even if previous job has failed and that is not default flow. You need to use pattern - `*`  to achieve that.

In Java Config, it would be like , `.on("*").to(...)` and so on.

Your pattern parameter to `on(..)` can be anything from [ExitStatus](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ExitStatus.html) and `*` provided you are not using any other custom statuses.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Perfect, a conditional flow fits just perfect to this problem. Thank you!